# React reducer wrong increment number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, reducers

I have a problem when I dispatch an action that triggers my ADD_TO_CART type. I want to increase the quantity of a specific number added in the cart when user click on it. The numbers I'm getting for quantity are : 1, 3, 5, 7, 9.. But they should be incremented only by 1 like 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. Why am I getting double increments in my if statement when I wanna update state indirectly without mutating it? Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Here is my code :

```
switch(action.type){
    case 'ADD_TO_CART':
        let tempCart = [...state.cart];
        let specificIndex = state.cart.findIndex((obj) => obj.id === action.item.id);
        if(specificIndex >= 0){
            tempCart[specificIndex].quantity +=1; // it should increment only by 1 and not by 2
            tempCart[specificIndex].price += action.item.price;
            return{
                ...state,
                cart : tempCart,
            }
        }
```

And here is my state for the example above:

```
export const initialState = {
cart: [],
};
```

Comment: Are you sure that this reducer is only called once? I suggest adding a console.log("test"); to first line of your reducer code to ensure that this reducer is called only once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this is because you are treating `tempCart` as *mutable* (adding to its members directly), when really it is just a reference to (*not* a copy of) part of `state`, which should always be treated as *immutable*. Instead, try something like the following:

```js
switch (action.type) {
  case "ADD_TO_CART":
    let specificIndex = state.cart.findIndex(
      (obj) => obj.id === action.item.id
    );
    if (specificIndex >= 0) {
      return {
        ...state,
        cart: state.cart.map((item, idx) =>
          idx == specificIndex
            ? {
                ...item,
                quantity: item.quantity + 1,
                price: item.price + action.item.price,
              }
            : item
        ),
      };
    }
}
```

See [Immutable Update Patterns](https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns/) for more. Note that, even in this small example, these sorts of updates can quickly become unwieldy. There are [helper libraries](https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns/#immutable-update-utility-libraries) available that can simplify the process, if you are so inclined.